# Given an interval of convergence for a series, how do I find what the series converges to?

Tags: analysis, power-series

What does this series converge to in its interval of convergence?

$\lim _{x\to \infty }\left(x+1\right)^n$

The interval of convergence for this series is $-2\:<\:x\:<\:0$

How would I go about finding what the series converges to within the interval of convergence?

Comment: if you are talking about $\sum (x+1)^n$ where $x \in (-2,0)$ that is just a convergent geometric series. Did you learn that? For example $1+1/2+\cdots = 2$? In general $a_n \rightarrow 0$ is just a nessesary condition for convergence of $\sum a_n$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If
$-2\:<\:x\:<\:0$,
then
$-1<x+1<1$.

What does this tell you
about $(1+x)^n$?